# How to post tweet using official Twitter app using intent and then returning to you app?

Tags: android, twitter, android-intent

I use this code to start posting on twitter using official Twitter app:

```
    Intent twitterIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); //Intent.ACTION_VIEW
    twitterIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.SEND");
    twitterIntent.setFlags(0x3000000);  
    twitterIntent.setType("text/plain");    
    twitterIntent.setClassName("com.twitter.android", "com.twitter.android.PostActivity");
    twitterIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ("Random post"));
    startActivity(twitterIntent);
```

I also check if this intent is available before using it with:

```
public static boolean canReceiveIntent (Intent intent, Context c) {

    PackageManager packageManager = c.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

    return isIntentSafe;
}
```

It works ok, but Twitter app remains opened after posting a tweet (on feed). I also tried using startActivityForresult(), but it crashes with error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: FORWARD_RESULT_FLAG used while also requesting a result
```

How to return to my app after posting tweet?

Answer (score 0):

IMO the official Twitter app is not respecting the Android Intent lifecycle by finishing itself after the ACTION_VIEW or ACTION_SEND Intent is received via a startActivityForResult method call, rather it is remaining open and breaking the experience for any apps that send it such Intents.